# I have reset my iPhone, now many contacts are lost, though I synced them through iCloud. Are they still in an old backup?

Tags: iphone, icloud, time-machine, contacts

I reset my iPhone 4 because it was terribly slow after 3 years of continuous usage.

Now it's much faster again, but many of my contacts are lost, although I used to sync them using iCloud and I had them both on my phone and on my Mac. I tried to restore them using TimeMachine, but it seems there are no backups for contacts left from early enough.

Now I wonder whether my contacts still are on an old iPhone backup (which I should have in iTunes from before resetting my iPhone) and so I could get them back.

So my question is: What could have happened that I lost most of my contacts? I indeed deleted a lot of contacts a few days ago, but I for sure didn't delete many of those that are gone, and many that I deleted, are back again.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what happened but you should be able to restore your iPhone from within iTunes. Depending on when the backup was made that should have *everything* that was on your iPhone.

If you have no backups in iTunes that work you can check Time Machine for other backups:

```
/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/
```

Restore your more recent backup to your local HD and then Option-Click on the restore from backup button in iTunes and select the file you just recovered.

I am doing some of this from memory but that is the general idea.